# Pandas read_sql db engine under flask-sqlachemy

Tags: python, pandas, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a web app in Flask, and I am using pandas to retrieve data from a MySQL DB. The following used to work, using what I read from another post:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config['default'])
db.init_app(app)
conn = db.engine.connect().connection
```

Then in the view function (in the same .py file):

```
@app.route('/report', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def report():
    form = ReportForm()
...
    sql = '''SELECT * FROM availability ...'''
    df = psql.read_sql(sql, conn)
...

    return render_template('report.html', form=form, df=df)
```

This webpage displays a table based on the date interval chosen (from the form).
I added inline editing of this table on the webpage via x-editable, and I see that the changes have been posted to the database, but if I submit the form again the table only loads up the old data before the change was made. I only see the changes after I reopen the webpage, which is very strange.

Moving the 'conn' line right before read_sql works:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM availability ...'''
conn = db.engine.connect().connection
df = psql.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

But this is not nice as I have to repeat this for every query I make (and there are a few for each view). Is there a way where I just declare this connection object once at the beginning and get it over with? SQLAlchemy's ORM works, but I prefer writing raw SQL in this case.

Edit:

joris' suggestion worked for one query, but now I ran into another error:

```
File "C:\Users\KF\flask-test\hello.py", line 107, in report
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql.format(vd='20140727', sd=sd, ed=ed), db.engine)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 363, in read_sql_query
parse_dates=parse_dates)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 823, in read_sql
result = self.execute(*args)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 810, in execute
return self.engine.execute(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1752, in execute
return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 721, in execute
return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 870, in _execute_text
statement, parameters
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 958, in _execute_context
context)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1163, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 951, in _execute_context
context)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\lightson\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 436, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
File "c:\users\kf\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-_444w8\MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 187, in execute
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

But the raw sql string is fine - I ran the query myself and is valid. Actual SQL:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM availability WHERE view_date = str_to_date('{vd}', '%Y%m%d') and book_date >= str_to_date('{sd}','%Y%m%d') and book_date <= str_to_date('{ed}', '%Y%m%d')'''
```

Here 'sd' and 'ed' are strings that look like '20140801'. Looks like I have to escape those '%'s for MySQL but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Edit:

Got it to work. Add another '%' in front of '%Y','%m' and '%d' to escape the percent signs.
Basically, as joris said, use `pd.read_sql_query` and you should be fine.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Starting from 0.14, you should just give the `engine` instead of a `connection` to `read_sql`. Does changing that solve the problem?

Comment: Using `df = psql.read_sql(sql, db.engine)` gives me this error: `OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1017, "Can't find file: '...`

Comment: Which version of pandas?

Comment: 0.14.1, so that shouldn't be a problem. not many examples of using read_sql floating around though...

Comment: Can you post the full error? Also, you don't need to import the `io.sql` module, it is now available as a top level funtion. And if you do a query, better to use the `pd.read_sql_query()` function (`read_sql` tries to delegate to that function if it gets a query, so using it directly is a step less).

Comment: please see the edit above. using read_sql_query gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you post even more of the error trace? It is strange you get the same error with `read_sql_query` as this should never interprete the query as a table name (this indeed does happen with `read_sql`, but this also should not give that error, but we have a similar report: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7826)

Comment: You can accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.

Comment: @joris do you happen to know how to dynamically add user input data to query a postgres db? I'm trying to use pd.read_sql_query and it works in python, but not Flask: `sq = '''SELECT noise, population_density, median_home_value, median_household_income, yearbuilt, vacant FROM lookup_table WHERE address=%(input_address)s;'''` `address_lookup = request.args.get('address')` `param = {'input_address':address_lookup}` `query_results = pd.read_sql_query(sq, con, params = param)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. For those who might need this in the future:
1.Add another '%' in front of '%Y','%m' and '%d' to escape the percent signs.
2.Like joris said, use `pd.read_sql_query` instead of `read_sql`.